# Finding British militia records?

Tags: 19th-century, military-records, scotland

According to Charles Ormond's marriage record (Church of Forfar, a Church of Scotland church) from 1804, he was a private in the 11th British militia.

When did he begin military service and when did he finish? What other military work (if any) was he involved in?

Comment: Could you clarify what the source is for your information?  What kind of marriage record do you have (OPR, non-conformist, etc.)?

Comment: Church of Forfar, I'm unsure of the denomination, though I believe it to be Church of Scotland.

Comment: @JanMurphy Just checked, definitely Church of Scotland

Comment: Married in Forfar 1804

Comment: Could you add that info to the question please?

Answer (score 6):

The answers, such as they are, are probably available only at Kew with the Muster Books and Pay Lists (that's one document produced every quarter, usually).  See [TNA Guide on Militia](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/help-with-your-research/research-guides/militia/)

The problem is that these books are usually very thin on genealogical data so it may not be possible to distinguish 2 people with the same name. Tracking how long someone served can only be done by following these books forward and back to see when someone appears and disappears.

The next issue is that 11th British Militia isn't a name of a unit. But given the Scottish context it should probably read 11th North British Militia (Regiment). The only way is to work on that basis. I have no idea quite where the 11th was based - my first check suggests that it wasn't one of the originals in Scotland - but the MB&PLs do indicate where a unit was.

Whether any local military museum in Scotland has any more data, I've no idea. Personnel papers for individual soldiers in this era only survive for those serving long enough to get a pension.

***To add a bit more detail***: 
The original poster has identified a page on the [Forfar & Kincardine Militia](http://www.pglforfarshire.org/Forfar_Kincardine_Militia.html) that says that the Forfarshire, or 8th North British Militia was raised in 1798, that it became the Forfarshire and Kincardine Militia in 1802, was disembodied but then re-embodied in 1803 as the 11th or Forfar(shire) and Kincardine Militia.

Assuming that page to be correct, and I have no reason to doubt it, then the relevant Muster Books & Pay Lists are those for the Forfar & Kincardine and are at Kew (using that version of the title so far as I can see), starting with:

Reference:  WO 13/778
Description:    Forfar & Kincardine
Date:   1798

and going through to

Reference:  WO 13/795
Description:    Forfar & Kincardine
Date:   1815

These are 1 piece per annum. The sequence then goes through to WO 13/803 but in multiple years per piece. However, while you should be able to find Charles Ormond in that lot (if the register entry is correct) and identify which year he joined and when he left (possibly even the exact dates given that these are Muster Books & *Pay* Lists), if there are 2 Charles Ormonds you may not be able to identify which is which.

As an example of the issues, I have looked at MB&PLs for the Volunteers of South Cheshire during the same era - I see names that match my relatives but nothing to identify whether the guy is my relative, not even which town or village in South Cheshire the soldier and his company come from.

Comment: The 11th British militia was the Forfar militia I believe: http://www.pglforfarshire.org/Forfar_Kincardine_Militia.html

Comment: That looks very plausible then. So you should start with seeing what Kew has for the Forfarshire & Kincardine. There also seems to be / have been a museum at Montrose with Muster Rolls for ,them. Can't see anything else in the Gibson Guide.

Comment: Nothing on their website after searching, and I wouldn't be in a position to travel to London without knowing they had any records. Do you think I would get anywhere by ringing them?

Comment: For quick pointers you can also reach TNA via live chat. Details here: https://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/contact-us/

Comment: Very good job with this answer Sir! As a final note, do you know if there is any way to determine whether he is present in these records without visiting London? I don't live nearby.

Comment: No, that would count as research needing, I guess, payment, because they'd need to get the stuff out and read it at a detailed level. I presume. Frankly, for what you'd get, and the risk of there being issues, I wouldn't make a special journey.